# Drupal and Domain

Tags: 7, redirection, subsites

I have a strange redirect if I access my Drupal installation without subdomain:

http://efg-zoar.de

leads to

http://www.efg-zoar.de/drupal7

and the "drupal7" is just wrong....
If I enter

www.efg-zoar.de

directly, everything works fine. I already asked my webspace provider for support, but these settings are completly fine. The Drupal installation was installed intially with an other domain. May this change cause this problem? And how can I fix this?

Thanks a lot!
Saduras

Edit:
I found some entries in the database table prefix_locales_source which has "/drupal7/install.php?profile=standard&locale=de" in the field 'location'.
Are these somehow related to my problem?

Comment: Did you check your A record for efg-zoar.de where is it pointing to? Did you change the .htaccess file at all?

Comment: The whole webspace is managed by Domainfactory and I can't set any IP configurations or A records. I just specified an path on the webspace for the domain and it's not possible to set a different path for the subdomain www (but for any other and they work perfect as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I acccess the URL http://efg-zoar.de/ in Firefox with the HttpFox extension installed, it shows this response header.

```
(Status-Line)   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date    Thu, 02 May 2013 21:45:41 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.22
Location    http://www.efg-zoar.de/drupal7/
```

This shows that you have Apache installed, and something is performing a server-side redirect. As an earlier post mentioned, this redirect might take place at different levels.

The web browser hits Apache first. Apache can store redirects in both the httpd.conf and .htaccess files. It sounds like you're hosting in a shared environment, so my bet would be the .htaccess file.

Apache then passes the request to PHP and Drupal. A four-line PHP file can perform the same redirect, as shown here. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/php-redirect/

I checked the headers when accessing the home page with the WWW prefix http://www.efg-zoar.de/. This shows the header X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10. This makes me suspect that http://efg-zoar.de/ is hitting plain Apache with no PHP or Drupal involved. Here's the header from http://www.efg-zoar.de/.

```
(Status-Line)   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date    Thu, 02 May 2013 22:02:30 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.22
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.10
X-Generator Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
```

You should contact your web host and ask them how to change the Apache redirect in either the .htaccess or httpd.conf file. Sometimes web hosts allow you to FTP the .htaccess file, but you need to configure your FTP client to show hidden files (file names preceded by a period, like .htaccess).

Here's the HttpFox extension for Firefox. It's helpful for debugging these issue.
https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem.
A wrong .htaccess file (for joomla) caused this one.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have this:

```
www.domain.de in /bla/bla/drupal7

domain.de in /bla/bla/drupal7
```

you need:

```
www.domain.de in /bla/bla

domain.de in /bla/bla
```

redirect folder /bla/bla via .htaccess or php to /bla/bla/drupal7

Comment: I tried something like this with an html-meta redirect. It work's indeed, but then I have the ugly URL www.efg-zoar.de/drupal7 as base url. I would like to get rid of the "drupal7" instead...